# Why isn't netcat udp message being recieved by netcat listener?

Tags: udp, netcat, statsd, datadog

I have netcat listening for udp traffic on port 8125 in terminal 1

`nc -ul 8125`

and in terminal 2 I run the following (a test dogstatsd message for troubleshooting a datadog client connection):

```zsh
echo "test_metric:1|c" | nc -u -w 1 -v localhost 8125
#found 0 associations
#found 1 connections:
#    1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
#   outif lo0
#   src ::1 port 50397
#   dst ::1 port 8125
#   rank info not available
#Connection to localhost port 8125 [udp/*] succeeded!
```

I would expect to see `test_metric:1|c` show up in the output of terminal 1, but there is no output at all.

Can you help me understand why the udp message is not showing up and how to successfully send the udp message?

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know why it makes a difference, but adding the `-4` option made it work

```
echo "test_metric:1|c" | nc -u -4 -w 1 localhost 8125
```

Here's the man page on the option:

> -4      Forces nc to use IPv4 addresses only.

Comment: Previously with localhost, you were sending on ::1, which is ipv6 address. 
And you were listening on ipv4 address 127.0.0.1.